# How can I compare two dates and return years or days depending on difference?

Tags: javascript, function, date

I have this problem. I want to compare TODAY with a date (month, day, year) and return the age in days or years, depending if difference is smaller (return days) or greater (return years) than 1 year.

I get odd results.

That's my code:

```js
function tellAge(month, day, year) {
 var d = new Date();
 var years = d.getFullYear()-year;
 var days = d.getDay()-day; 

 if ((d.getFullYear()-year)>1) {
  return "You are " + days + " days old"
 } else {
  return "You are " + years + " year old"
 }
 }

tellAge(3,11,2017)
```

This: tellAgeTest(3,11,2017) should return

> You are 2 years old

but does not.

Comment: Look at your if statement. You are saying `if years > 1 return days old`. You have it flipped. Should be doing the years statement in this case. And a nitpick, you calculated the years into your `years` variable but you aren't using it. Make your if statement `if(years > 1)`. For future reference when you get incorrect results please post the results you're getting. Its hard to help for most issues without knowing what the error is

Comment: And what is it returning?

Comment: "You are -9 days old"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work even if you fix the comparison operator.

In your current code you are subtracting `d.getDay()`, which is the day of the month (3 for Sept. 3rd) from the day entered (17 for Jan. 17th, in my example). This would work if both of the dates were in the same month, but if you want it to work across several months you have to count the number of days between the two dates and not just the difference between the days of the month.

```js
function tellAge(month, day, year) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthday = new Date(year, month-1, day);
  var days = (today - birthday) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  
  if (days < 365) {
    return "You are " + Math.floor(days) + " days old"
  } else {
    return "You are " + Math.floor(days/365) + " years old"
  }
}

console.log(tellAge(1, 17, 2019));
console.log(tellAge(3, 11, 2017));
```

Comment: Can you help me think it through: 

"If you use a date less than a year you're only counting the day of the month entered from the day of the current month" AS COMPARED TO _________

Comment: Also, do you deduct the month-1 because months are counted from 0-11?

Comment: @user2132380 - I've edited the answer to try to make it more clear. And yes, months are zero indexed, hence the `-1`.

Comment: May I ask another thing? What are your calculating here
`var days = (today - birthday) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);`

are both dates (today & Birthday) in miliseconds? If yes I assume you want to transform it to seconds (/1000), then to minutes (/60), then to hours (/60), then to days (/24). So a number of millliseconds expressed as days, right?

I'm just confused becuase today results in something like this *Wed Sep 04 2019 12:05:08 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)* and not in a number of milliseconds

Comment: @user2132380 - your assumption is exactly right. a date object is shown in the console as a string (like *Wed Sep 04 2019 12:05:08 GMT+0200*) but since javascript is [loosly typed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) you can do math with it and the computer will automatically convert the date object to the number of [milliseconds since unix epoch time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#User_notes).

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is backwards. you should check for less than 1 not greater than one. Like this:

```js
function tellAge(month, day, year) {
  var d = new Date();
  var years = d.getFullYear() - year;
  var days = d.getDay() - day;

  if ((d.getFullYear() - year) < 1) { // This comparison was backwards
    return "You are " + days + " days old"
  } else {
    return "You are " + years + " year old"
  }
}
```

Comment: this is wrong. try `tellAge(1, 17, 2019)`. it will subtract 17 from 3, because it's the third of september, which makes no sense.